# Are there any Prism "Post-build" Event or method while using MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, prism, mef

I have 4+ imported properties in a class and some code that needs at least 4 properties to execute

Are there any PRISM or MEF events that would help instead of putting notify on each setter and then checking for nulls ?

Comment: Does MEF integrate with ISupportInitialize? Try implementing this interface on your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your class implement the [IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.ipartimportssatisfiednotification.aspx) interface. Then the [OnImportsSatisfied](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us?query=OnImportsSatisfied%20&x=7&y=6) method will be called once all the imports have been satisfied. Put your "post-build" code in this method.

This way you know all your parts have been imported and that it is safe to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Aspect Orientated Programming language, such as Spec#, see http://specsharp.codeplex.com/

This will allow you to place an attribute on the class, and spec# will add the notify property changed as a post build event.

Comment: will take a look for research but looking for c# for now